# Contenteditable paragraphs in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a contenteditable paragraph in html. I have a button which on clicking will make the text bold. The first time it is clicked the text should change to bold,and the next time it is clicked ,the text should be normal(not bolder).This is similar to the **Stack overflow** question editor.html code:

```
    <button type="button" id="bold" onclick="bold()">B</button>
    <div id="content">
       <p id="hey" contenteditable="true">Hi how are you</p>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
        let boldClick=0;
        let p=document.getElementById('hey');
        function bold(){
           if(boldClick%2==0){ 

             p.innerHTML=p.innerHTML+' <span contenteditable="true">'+' boldtext'+'</span>';
           }
           else{
              let pNew=document.createElement('p');
              pNew.setAttribute("contenteditable","true");
              document.getElementById('content').appendChild(pNew);
           }
           boldClick++;
        }
```

CSS:

```
        #bold{
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        span{
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color: grey;
        }
        p{
            display: inline;
        }
```

I can make the text bolder by clicking the button.Bolder texts must be inside the **span** element and non-bolder texts must be outside **span** but inside 
  **p** element.How do I solve it?

Comment: change the `font-weight` during odd clicks, or add a class on even clicks and on odd clicks remove them

Comment: Bolder texts should be inside the span element and non-bolder texts should be outside of `<span>` but inside of `<p>` element.

Comment: well then change the css for the span element or add/remove class for the span element

Comment: Can you explain it with answer?

Answer (score 2):

**approach 1:**

```
    let boldClick=0;
    let p=document.getElementById('hey');
    p.innerHTML=p.innerHTML+' <span contenteditable="true" id="bold">'+' boldtext'+'</span>';
     const boldTag = document.getElementById('bold');
    function bold(){
       if(boldClick%2==0){ 
      boldTag.style.fontWeight="";
       }
       else{
         boldTag.style.fontWeigh="bold";
       }
       boldClick++;
    }
```

**approach 2:**

```
    let boldClick=0;
    let p=document.getElementById('hey');
    p.innerHTML=p.innerHTML+' <span contenteditable="true" id="bold">'+' boldtext'+'</span>';
     const boldTag = document.getElementById('bold');
    function bold(){
       if(boldClick%2==0){ 
      boldTag.id="";
       }
       else{
         boldTag.id="bold";
       }
       boldClick++;
    }
```

these approaches are not optimized , but hope you get the concept .

Answer (score 1):

the shortest way. Create a class named Bold. Add the properties you want to this class. Select elements with Javascript and assign a function to have this class. 
In general , creating a class with css and using javascript is the simplest way to solve problems, which element of this class should be added when.

```js
let clicked = false;

function bold() {
  let paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraph");
  let span = document.getElementById("span");

  if (clicked) {
    span.contentEditable = false;
    span.classList.remove("bold");
    clicked = false;
  } else {
    span.contentEditable = true;
    span.classList.add("bold");
    clicked = true;
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  display: inline;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="bold-button" onclick="bold()">B</button>
<div id="content">
  <p id="paragraph">Hi how are you
    <span id="span">how are you</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Here,the change is applicable to the whole paragraph.But I want a specific text alone to be bold (just like in the stack overflow ask question editor)

Comment: Updated answer. Do you want like this ?

Comment: Not exactly. The span tag should be added only when we need a bold text. Non-bolder text should be added in the <p> tag.

Comment: Updated again. Check the answer. thickening will now work only for the span label.

Answer (score 0):

First off, please tag your post with java script instead of java, similar name, different language. Here is the code you should use:

```
let isBold = false;
let p=document.getElementById('hey');

function bold(){
    if(isBold == false){ 
        p.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        isBold = true;
    }
    else{
        p.style.fontWeight = "normal";
        isBold = false;
    }
}
```

It changes the font weight (if it is bold or not) instead of the complex code you had. If you are just turning something on and off (bold or not) then use a boolean value (true + false) true will make it bold, false will make it normal. For HTML graphics, you should use CSS language. You can change the variable's CSS values by saying style then the thing you want to change.

Comment: This will actually make the whole paragraph element bold .But I want a specific text alone to be bolder,that's why I have added the span element

Comment: Ah, okay, so you want to change the boldClick to a bool value and change the if statements to work with bool statements. And remove the boldClick++;